# Grafana: a line graph without date-time on x-axis

Tags: graph, data-visualization, grafana, dashboard

This is probably more complicated as it sounds, at least with Grafana.

I have an experiment, where for every location (1-100) a value is changed over time. I want to show this with a line graph (or a bar graph), where x-axis correspond to the locations (1-100) and y-axis correspond to the average value for this location for the time interval that is set in Grafana in the upper right corner. Data comes from database. Please, suggest me, which type of graph (dashboard) should I choose in Grafana to achieve the goal. I can only see two kinds of them, those with time on x-axis and those of type histogram but none seems to be applicable.

Comment: You have problem that you have non timeseries data. You may use `Graph (old)` panel type (in Grafana 8) with `X-Axis Mode: Series`.

Comment: @JanGaraj that only show series as Aggregate value (min,max,avg...), not original series values as time series is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have implemented the graph using natel-plotly-panel plugin.

```
 "panels": [
    {
      "pconfig": {
        "traces": [
          {
            "mapping": {
              "color": "64",
              "size": null,
              "text": "metriccat",
              "x": "loccat",
              "y": "valuecat",
              "z": null
            },
            "name": "My value",
            "show": {
              "line": true,
              "lines": true,
              "markers": false
            }
          },
          ...
        ]
      },
      "pluginVersion": "7.5.5",
      "targets": [
        {
          "format": "table",
          "group": [],
          "metricColumn": "none",
          "rawQuery": true,
          "rawSql": "SELECT\n  avg(column_with_values) AS valuecat,\n  loc loccat,\n  avg(column_with_values) as metriccat\nFROM ... \nWHERE\n  $__timeFilter(timestamp)\nGROUP BY loc\n\n",
          "select": [
            [
              {
                "params": [
                  "value"
                ],
                "type": "column"
              }
            ]
          ],
          "timeColumn": "time",
          "where": [
            {
              "name": "$__timeFilter",
              "params": [],
              "type": "macro"
            }
          ]
        },
        ...
      ],
      "title": "Average Values Along the Locations",
      "type": "natel-plotly-panel",
      "version": 1
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

seems Grafana builtin panels only support
`time series`, which mean x-axis must be 'time' type.

### bilibala-echarts-panel

I use this third-part panel `bilibala-echarts-panel`
https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/bilibala-echarts-panel/

achieved the goal: x-axis not use time value.

It can use a custom callback function, to handle data and render

---

#### setting

in grafana query setting:

- format as `time series`
  // time series need 3 column:

  - time // time or number (can be parse as time)
  - metric // string: series name
  - value // number (otherwise got value error)
- assign the value to time column.
  // it may rander as 1970-01 in table view, but in echart we can read it as number

in echart panel option:
　`data.series` got the grafana data
　// convert/adapte it to echart data here.

---

maybe format as `table` can have more flexible data,
　and parse them in the callback js.

#### summary

grafana and echart have different theory,
　have to understand both of them ,
　and do the convert in js.

// bilibala-echarts-panel using echart v4 @2022-07